# Map multiple checkboxes component with same props using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display 2 CustomFields with a loop

```
{customFields.map((p) => <CustomField parentKey='customFields' {...p} />)}
```

the customField code looks like this

```
const CustomField = ({
  id,
  type,
  label,
  description,
  required,
  allowMultipleUploads,
  forToggle,
  parentKey,
}) => {
  const name = parentKey ? `${parentKey}.${id}` : id;
  const [isCheckboxClicked, setIsCheckboxClicked] = useState(false);

  switch (type) {
    case 'toggle':
      return (
        <>
          <Checkbox name='toggleCheck' onClick={(e) => { setIsCheckboxClicked(!isCheckboxClicked); }}>
            <Body>{label}</Body>
          </Checkbox>
          {forToggle.type === 'text' && isCheckboxClicked && (
            <Field type='text' placeholder={`Enter ${label}`} name={name} description={description} />
          )}
          {forToggle.type === 'file_upload' && isCheckboxClicked && (
            <FileUploadField name={name} description={description} onlyOne={!forToggle.allowMultipleUploads} />
          )}
        </>
      );

    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

I am using `isCheckboxClicked` to display either CustomField. but when In the mapping loop, there are 2 fields and both are toggle. I am having an issue with `isCheckboxClicked`. It only attaches with one CustomField but not both.

[image]

it's working fine for the first CustomField but not the 2nd one, I am looking for a way to make `isCheckboxClicked` dynamic so it can work with both 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the key

[for more details](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
{customFields.map((p,index) => <CustomField key={index} parentKey='customFields' {...p} />)}
```

---

```
const CustomField = ({
  id,
  type,
  label,
  description,
  required,
  allowMultipleUploads,
  forToggle,
  parentKey,
}) => {
  const name = parentKey ? `${parentKey}.${id}` : id;
  const [isCheckboxClicked, setIsCheckboxClicked] = useState(false);

  switch (type) {
    case 'toggle':
      return (
        <>
          <Checkbox key={id} name='toggleCheck' onClick={(e) => { setIsCheckboxClicked(!isCheckboxClicked); }}>
            <Body>{label}</Body>
          </Checkbox>
          {forToggle.type === 'text' && isCheckboxClicked && (
            <Field type='text' placeholder={`Enter ${label}`} name={name} description={description} />
          )}
          {forToggle.type === 'file_upload' && isCheckboxClicked && (
            <FileUploadField name={name} description={description} onlyOne={!forToggle.allowMultipleUploads} />
          )}
        </>
      );

    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: its still the same behavior  ,nothing changed